# Problem with size of lower indexed letters like: j,p,q,g etc. inside PDF files

Tags: pdf, itext

Dear Stack Overflow Members ...

I try to cover words in PDF.
I have choose word: 'informacji' to be deleted from entire PDF file.
Problem is that i cannot get the right size of letter: 'j'- in this case.
[image]

Someone more clever, could gess what is written behind it.

I have implemented my own class inherited from `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` , here is the code:

```
 public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.GetRise() != 0)
        { // remove the rise from the baseline - we do this because the text from a super/subscript render operations should probably be considered as part of the baseline of the text the super/sub is relative to 
            Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise());
            segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
       var fnt= renderInfo.GetFont();

        TextChunk tc = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), tclStrat.CreateLocation(renderInfo, segment));
        Vector startLine = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
        Vector endLineTopRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
        Rectangle textRectangle = new Rectangle(startLine[Vector.I1], startLine[Vector.I2], endLineTopRight[Vector.I1], endLineTopRight[Vector.I2]);
        TextInfo textInfo = new TextInfo(tc, textRectangle);
        locationalResult.Add(textInfo);
    }
```

and some lines code later, im adding values of `textRectangle` object to the list of objects `wordList[wordList.Count-1].rectanglesToDraw.Add(new SquaresToDraw(page, text.textRectangle.Left, text.textRectangle.Bottom, text.textRectangle.Right, text.textRectangle.Top));`

Now additional info (nothing special imo):

`RectanglesToDraw` is a list of `SquaresToDraw`

And `SquaresToDraw` is a class, which looks like:

```
 public class SquaresToDraw
{
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public float left { get; set; }//llx
    public float bottom { get; set; }  //lly
    public float right { get;set;} //rux
    public float top { get; set; }//ruy
    public SquaresToDraw(int pageNumber,float left, float bottom, float right,float top)
    {
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.top = top;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the base line add lower limit of your rectangle:

```
Vector startLine = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
```

If you want to cover letters with parts below the base line, too, you should use the descent line instead:

```
Vector startLine = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
```

Comment: Btw, someone downvoted mine question, do you have a clue why ? I think its kinda clear... but maybe not ?

Comment: I agree, very clear question, you did your research. We need more questions like this on Stack Overflow. I upvoted to negate the downvote.

Comment: Im always open for a constructive feedback, even more for a positive one ;)  Thanks for a honest response.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik if you get a downvote every once in a while, there is nothing to worry about - often there are as many opinions about the quality of a question or answer as there are readers of it. If you get downvotes often, though, you should worry.

Comment: Thats fair enough mkl, again thank you for your solution, as also for many others... Now im heading for work with Nicomsoft OCR libraries to cover images with forbidden words in PDF ;)